# .gitignore How to exclude all direct files of a specific folder but include all subfolders of that folder?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to exclude all direct files of the folder `reports` but include all subfolders.
At first I didn't knew that there were any subfolders in this folder and I pushed `reports/*`, to not push any automatically generated reports. 
But now all the template files in the subfolders are marked as deleted in the staging area, and I want to fix this:

**Exclude:**

- reports/report1.pdf
- reports/report2.txt
- reports/report3PlainFile
- ...

**Include:**

- reports/A/a_1_template.rpt
- reports/A/a_2_template.rpt
- reports/B/a_2_template.rpt
- ...

I have tried:

```
    reports/*
    !reports/*/
```

and

```
    reports/*
    !reports/*/*
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Now everyting in the `reports` folder is excluded. 
But I want to only exclude all direct files and include all subfolders (and their contents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.gitignore` file content:

```
/*
!/*/
```

First ignore everything then exclude folders recursively from the last match (everything).

**Update**

```
folder/*
!folder/*/
```

Comment: If you add an actual foldername to your response, I'll mark it as accepted. Like: `folder/*` and `!folder/*/`

Comment: @ It works for all folders and their subfolders excluding the root files (general solution). If just some folders needs to be included then as you said it should be changed to `!folder/*/` at desired level.

Answer (score 0):

*Please note that in .gitignore you only exclude files.
*To be focused on your question the answer is that you have to navigate to each file manually and let the nested paths intact.

But in general:

First of all you have to start your .gitignore file with

```
*/**/.gitignore
```

,so that the git not take this file to be shared
and continue with

```
**/target/*   
**/*.xml
```

,the idea is to include eather the file itself as

```
filename.xml
```

,or by navigation with * as
in the xml line you want to exclude all the files that are of type .xml while in the target you want to exclude all the files that this file contains.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer my question.
My question has nothing to do with Intellij.

Comment: It is not about focusing in the file types but in the way that you have to navigate to the files.

Comment: But I don't know the file extension of the generated files yet. They are generated on the fly. They can be .pdf or .txt or something I don't know before.

Answer (score 0):

Actually:

```
    reports/*
    !reports/*/
```

worked. The problem was somewhere else.

I pushed `reports/*` on Branch A and merged it into Branch B.

So all the template files were still present on Branch A but were marked as deleted in the staging area of Branch B. So I switched back to Branch A and added `!reports/*/` in the .gitignore file. Then I merged Branch A a second time into Branch B and discarded everything from the staging area of Branch B and now the subfolders (and content) are back in Branch B.